# Deleting entire row using macro in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I have and excel spreadsheet and I need to make a button that deletes the entire row in which the button is located.

Lets say I have a button on cell G7. When I press it, I want the entirety of row 7 to be deleted and everything under that shifted up.

This can be easily hardcoded to delete row 7, but I want to have a button located on every row up to ~30, so at G1, G2, G3,..., G30, and when I press it, I want it to only delete the row on which it is located.
Example: I press a button on G7, everything under row 7 is shifted up, so row 8 becomes row 7 and so on. I then press button at G9, and I want row 9 (not 10, which it used to be before first pressing button at G7) to be deleted.

Is is possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have the button execute based on its `topleftcell.row`

`s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row` will give you the row number as `s` so just plug it into where your deletion is

using `application.caller` you *should* be able to have all buttons execute the same macro, but I'm not 100%. Check the reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267597/more-information-about-application-caller-with-vba-in-excel)